# Error using googletrans api in python translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

I want to translate some text using googletrans.
This is my code:

```
inputtext = "Ich mag Schokolade"

srclang = "de"
dstlang = "en"

translation = Translator.translate(text=inputtext, src=srclang, dest=dstlang)
```

But when I run it, this Error comes up:

> translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize an instance of `Translator`:

```
translator = Translator()
inputtext = "Ich mag Schokolade"

srclang = "de"
dstlang = "en"

translation = translator.translate(text=inputtext, src=srclang, dest=dstlang)
```

`translate(...)` is not a static method of `Translator` so you need to call it on an instance rather than class.